# QuickFix subscribe on multiple symbols

Tags: c#, quickfix

There is the following problem: The supplier of liquidity has own protocol implementation of FIX (additional fields and some restrictions on the basis of FIX4.2). In general it is the same FIX, except for that fact that NoRelatedSym may contain only one instrument(security)(it is impossible to add all instruments to NoRelatedSym). This supplier of liquidity told me that on each instrument it is necessary to have separate stream. I set up quickfixengine configuration with one session. Through this session I do MarketDataRequest on a certain instrument(work good). However when I do MarketDataRequest on one more instrument- I start receiving updates only on it. Tell me please, whether there is an opportunity through one session to subscribe for a set of instruments, without using adding of all symbols in NoRelatedSym.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First this would be a question better suited for www.fixtradingcommunity.org/ but...

IMO yes its possible to use multiple instruments on one stream... this can be done by using tag 55 **and 460** in you 35=V message, but if your supplier does not process 460 or any other type of identifier, then they wouldnt be able to differentiate between products that use the same symbology.  For example:
55=ES (Eversource Energy - NYSE)
and 
55=ES (E-Mini S&P 500 - CME)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a general FIX or QuickFIX question, this is a counterparty-specific question.

FIX is a very simple protocol.  At its core, it's just a message-exchanging protocol.  All the message definitions are just suggestions, and counterparties don't have to support anything they don't want to.

> This supplier of liquidity told me that on each instrument it is necessary to have separate stream.

Then it sounds like the answer to your question is "no", and I think you kind of already know that.

Any further questions about this connection should be directed to your counterparty.

Comment: Thanks for the response! But I after all more am interested in functionality of QuickFix. I need to know for certain that it is impossible using one session and without using NoRelatedSym to realize a subscription to a set of instruments. If you answer that it is necessary to add all symbols to NoRelatedSym and differently it is impossible is will be for me the response. In advance many thanks!

Comment: THIS IS NOT ABOUT QUICKFIX.  **FIX is just a messaging protocol, and QF only sends and receives messages!**  FIX does not mandate the content of the messages, nor does it dictate how parties should use them (the default message dictionaries are just suggestions, not requirements).  You can construct any message you want and send it to your counterparty, and they'll respond however they want.  **Only your counterparty can answer your question! Check their docs and ask their support!**